# How to send email verification code (not link) to user create account with email

Tags: firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

I want to send **email verification code** *(not link)* to user's create an account on my website with email.

Using firebase authentication, the method is `send Email Verification`.

Problem is firebase sends a verification link to user's email. Is it possible to send verification code of 6 number to user's email if yes then how it can be done?

Thanks.